# talking to PouchDB Basics

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

maybe it's an absolutely stupid question, but I have a Pouchdb Database that looks like this:

```
var fragDB = {
        _id: new Date().toISOString(),
        question: quest,
        right: right,
        wrong1: wrong1,
        wrong2: wrong2,
        wrong3: wrong3,
        source1: source1,
        source2: source2,
        tags: tagarr
    }

    db.put(fragDB);
```

Now I want to retrieve the tags from the last document as an Array. I tried something like this, but this obviously didn't work.

```
var alltags = function(){

    db.allDocs({include_docs: true, limit: 1, descending: true}, function(err, response){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log("loading Standard Tags");
            return ["..."];
        }
        if (response){
            console.log(response.tags);
            return response.tags;
        }
    });
};
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not a dumb question – it just hard to grok, because PouchDB is asynchronous: http://pouchdb.com/guides/async-code.html

In your code, you have a function within a function, and it's the **sub-function** that's returning `response.tags`, not the parent function.

I suggest you read up on the link above, so you can learn how to write promisey async code like e.g.:

```
db.allDocs({
  include_docs: true, 
  limit: 1, 
  descending: true
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.tags);
  return response.tags;
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log("loading Standard Tags");
  return ["..."];
}).then(function (tags) {
  // do something with the tags
});
```

Comment: I don't know, if this is really the problem, cause setting "console.log(response.tags)" to "console.log(response)" shows the right object as well in your as in my suggestion. For me it seems the syntax to be wrong, cause I am not able to access this document correctly.

Comment: Oh right, sorry. Your `response` object actually contains the list of documents, so it should be `response.rows[0].tags`

Comment: Actually it's `response.rows[0].doc.tags` I found it out just a second a go. Thanks for your help